# changing a dataframe based on another dataframe in python

Tags: python, dataframe

Assume that we have a dataframe df1[1000,7] and another dataframe df2[300,6].
I am setting an example to understand my problem.

```
df1:  
 col1    col2      col3           ...     col8     newcol
 alex    george    whatever       ...     maria    nan
 julia   bill      sea            ...     paul     nan
 ...     ...        ...           ...     ...      nan
 chris   paul      micheal        ...     alex     nan
```

my df2 is a subset of df for example the following:

```
df2:
 col1    col2      col3           ...     col8     
 alex    george    whatever       ...     maria    
 chris   paul      micheal        ...     alex
```

I want the new column in my df to get specific values depending if the row exists in my df2. For example let s say here I want to write 'ok' if the row exists and 'missing' if it doesn't. Thus my df should become

```
df1:  
 col1    col2      col3           ...     col8     newcol
 alex    george    whatever       ...     maria    ok
 julia   bill      sea            ...     paul     missing
 ...     ...        ...           ...     ...      ...
 chris   paul      micheal        ...     alex     ok
```

how can I do that with one command without using for loops in python?
I have thought of using fill.na command to write "missing" after i have inserted the values for the rows that exist in my df, however I am a bit confused on the syntax on how to fill the values for the rows that exist in df2

EDIT: I noticed I inserted the newcol by accident in df2. It does not exist there

Answer (score 2):

I would simply merge (although technically there's no extra column you are merging) the 2 dataframes using the left as your "main" one. If you include the indicator though, it will create a column telling you if the rows are in both dataframes. So here, obviously if you see `"both"`, it's "ok" and `"left_only"`, it is "missing".

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame([
    ['alex','george','maria'],
    ['julia','bill','paul'],
    ['chris','paul','alex']
    ], columns = ['col1','col2', 'col3'])


df2 = pd.DataFrame([
    ['alex','george','maria'],
    ['chris','paul','alex']
    ], columns = ['col1','col2', 'col3'])


merged = df1.merge(df2, how='left', on=list(df1.columns), indicator=True)
df1['newcol'] = np.where(merged['_merge'] == 'both', 'ok', 'missing')
```

**Output:**

```
print(merged)
    col1    col2   col3     _merge
0   alex  george  maria       both
1  julia    bill   paul  left_only
2  chris    paul   alex       both
```

And with the new column to `df1`:

```
print(df1)
    col1    col2   col3   newcol
0   alex  george  maria       ok
1  julia    bill   paul  missing
2  chris    paul   alex       ok
```

Comment: Hello! But when I merge it, how does it insert the new values? Since the newcol is empty in df1 and it does not exist in df2

Comment: If it doesn't exist in df2, why would they have the same number of columns? "df1[1000,6] and another dataframe df2[300,6]"

Comment: Add secondly, you would be inputting those values using `np.where()`

Comment: hey @chitown88. Thank you again for replying! Yeah it was my mistake I was not clear enough on the description of the problem. How should I use np.where()?

Comment: No problem. It's in the code I have up above. `df1['newcol'] = np.where(merged['_merge'] == 'both', 'ok', 'missing')`

Comment: hello again @chitown88 . If I wanted to be more generic, and wanted instead of the values 'ok' , 'missing' wanted to insert values from df2 then what would I do? For example, inserting nan whenever the row does not exist, but insert the name from col3 of df2 into the new col of df1 whenever the row exists

Comment: `df1['newcol'] = np.where(merged['_merge'] == 'both', df2['col3'], np.nan)`

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try this -

```
n_columns = len(df1.columns)
df1["newcol"] = (df1 == df2).apply(sum, axis=1).apply(lambda x: "ok" if x == n_columns else "missing")
df1
```